# When I use dependecy injection like @Inject in my entity class it throw an error

Tags: java, dependency-injection, ejb, java-ee-7, erp

```
@Stateless
public class MyAccountsBean {

    @Inject SomeEntityClass someOtherBean;
    @Resource UserTransaction jtaTx;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="AccountsPU") EntityManager em;
    @Resource QueueConnectionFactory accountsJMSfactory;
    @Resource Queue accountPaymentDestinationQueue;

    public List<Account> processAccounts(DepartmentId id) {
        // Use all of above instance variables with no additional setup.
        // They automatically partake in a (server coordinated) JTA transaction
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

There are likely multiple issues, but one that sticks out is that all of the fields should be marked with the `private` modifier.

In addition, can you post the rest of your codebase and the error you are getting?